# Averageifs based on multiple dropdowns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an averageifs statement based on multiple criteria in dropdown boxes, referencing data in a separate sheet that connects to an ETL query. please ignore criteria in cell D8, and E31-34 is where i need to write the forumlas.

**[Dropdown]**

[image]

[Data]

[image]

Comment: Please use text, not an image to describe your problem. Giving an example input and expected output would be far more helpful.

Comment: Also include what you already tried.

Comment: I actually included two images, not sure why the other isn't showing up, but there's no way to describe in text without showing an image. There are multiple dropdown boxes with data validation so you choose an option from a list and then need it to average column O in the second image based on those inputs and output this average in the column that says "CTR" in the first image,

Comment: removed `vba` tag and added `excel-formula` tag, since it's formula related and not vba

Answer (score 0):

Formula for D31:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!O:O,Data!A:A,D5,Data!C:C,D8,Data!B:B,D11,Data!H:H,D17)
```

Formula For D32:D34 (drag down):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!O:O,Data!A:A,$D$5,Data!C:C,$D$8,Data!B:B,$D$11,Data!H:H,$D$17,Data!E:E,$B32)
```

The only thing that didn't make sense to me is the `AMS product` drop down, but I am sure you can adjust the formula to add that. The only issue you may have is if `ALL` is an option versus a specific product. The `AVERAGEIFS` formula will be slightly different (see two examples I gave you), so you may need an `IF` statement.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your help, but that's giving me a #DIV! error. Below is what I actually put in since "data" isn't actually the name of the tab.

D31

=AVERAGEIFS('ETL Query'!O:O,'ETL Query'!A:A,D5,'ETL Query'!C:C,D8,'ETL Query'!B:B,D11,'ETL Query'!H:H, D17)

and then D32:34

=AVERAGEIFS('ETL Query'!O:O,'ETL Query'!A:A,$D$5,'ETL Query'!C:C,$D$8,'ETL Query'!B:B,$D$11,'ETL Query'!H:H,$D$17,'ETL Query'!E:E,$B32)

Comment: @Linette - `#DIV! error` means there's no data that fits the criteria. Ensure the cell references are correct and ensure that the specific set of criteria actually has results in the data set. The structure I presented is solid, you just have to make sure it maps 100% accurately to your data set.

Comment: You're right!  I forgot that I limited the data in the ETL query tab because it was too big for me to email to a co worker.  Thanks so much!